# Training classifier as a batch processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, machine-learning, batch-processing, nltk

I am training classifier using large dataset(15 data files each with `5 * 10^5` features) in nltk,

So I am getting stuck in between wit this error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "term_classify.py", line 51, in <module>
    classifier = obj.run_classifier(cltype)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/nlp/nltk/publish/lists/classifier_function.py", line 146, in run_classifier
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 210, in train
    count = feature_freqdist[label, fname].N()
MemoryError
```

code:

```python
def run_classifier(self,cltype):
    # create our dict of training data
    texts = {}
    texts['act'] = 'act'
    texts['art'] = 'art'
    texts['animal'] = 'anim'
    texts['country'] = 'country'
    texts['company'] = 'comp'
    train_set = [] 
    train_set = train_set + [(self.get_feature(word), sense) for word in features]
    #len of train_set = 545668. Better if we can push 100000 at a time
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

Is there any way to train classifier in batches or anyother way so that load can be reduced, witouht affect result

Comment: I assumed you meant `10e5` when you said `lacks`, so I modified that. Feel free to rollback if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can always switch to `scikit-learn` Bayes which supports batch learning (partial fit)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB

> **partial_fit(X, y, classes=None, sample_weight=None)**
>
> Incremental fit on
> a batch of samples. This method is expected to be called several times
> consecutively on different chunks of a dataset so as to implement
> out-of-core or online learning. This is especially useful when the
> whole dataset is too big to fit in memory at once. This method has
> some performance overhead hence it is better to call partial_fit on
> chunks of data that are as large as possible (as long as fitting in
> the memory budget) to hide the overhead.